# prove the integral function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $f: [a,b]\times [c,d]\to \mathbb{R}, (x,\alpha)\to f(x,\alpha)$ is a 2 variable continuous function on $[a,b]\times [c,d]$, then $h(\alpha )=\int _a^b f(x, \alpha )dx$ is a continuous function on $[c,d]$.

My attempt: I've tried to prove this using the definition of 2-var continuous (that is, for any $(x, \alpha)$, $\epsilon >0$, $\exists \delta$, all $(y, \beta)$ satisfies $\sqrt{(y-x)^2+(\beta-\alpha)^2}<\delta$ yields $|f(y, \beta)-f(x, \alpha)|<\epsilon$) but since $\epsilon$ depends on $x$ so I can't go directly from here.Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $I:=[a,b]\times [c,d]$ is compact, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $I$.

Let $ \epsilon >0$. Then there is $ \delta>0$ such that

$|f(x,u)-f(x,v)|< \epsilon$ for all $(x,u),(x,v) \in I$ with $|u-v|< \delta$.

For $u,v \in [c,d]$ with $|u-v|< \delta$ we therefore get

$$|h(u)-h(v)| \le \int _a^b |f(x, u )-f(x,v)|dx \le (b-a) \epsilon.$$

Thus we have shown a little bit more: $h$ is uniformly continuous on $[c,d]$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the projection of a continuous function onto any coordinate is continuous, and the integral of a continuous real function is continuous.

---

In a general sense, we may *define* the space $\mathbb{R}^2$ to be the collection of ordered pairs from $\mathbb{R}$, equipped with the property that the projection of any continuous function onto either coordinate is always continuous. This is one possible way to define the *product topology* on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (which happens to be just the usual Euclidean topology).