# does $f(x,y)$ continuous imply $\int_{a}^{b} f(x,y) \,dx $ is continuous with respect to y?

Tags: calculus, integration

let $f(x,y)$ be a continuous function define $ \int_{a}^{b} f(x,y) \,dx $ as a function of y $g(y)$. Is $g(y)$ continuous ?
I tried to link this by Fundamental Theorem of calculus by setting $F(x,y)=  \int_{a}^{x} f(t,y) \,dt $.
However I could not show it is continuous or not with respect to y. Any help would be appreciated!
Edit:
Is this valid ? $\lim_{y \to y_0} \int_{a}^{b} f(x,y) \,dx = \int_{a}^{b}\lim_{y \to y_0}f(x,y)=\int_{a}^{b}f(x,y_0)=g(y_o)$ .

Comment: What have you tried so far? What will you end up with, when trying to use the definition of $g$ being continuous?

Comment: @user408858 I edited the question can I take this limit inside since $f$  is cont?

Comment: Your argument is not valid, yet, in my opinion. You need some sort of knowledge to change integration and limit. This is not obvious. Which definition of continuity do you know? Do you know the epsilon-delta-criterion?

Comment: epsilon and delta definition. Actually I am confused there. When can I change the position of integral and limit?

Comment: Try to use this definition first. What happens if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are close to each other, what do you need to show?

Comment: @user408858 okay I will try again

Comment: @OliverDiaz by finite you mean a bounded interval? like [0,1]

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2060964/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3884878/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24g(y)%20%3D%20%5Cint_%7Ba%7D%5E%7Bb%7D%20f(x%2Cy)%20%5C%2Cdx%24%20%2C%20continuous)

Comment: @MartinR thanks a lot!! I will use it!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $F(y)=\int^a_bf(x, y)\,dx$, where $f$ is continuous on a finite box $[a,b]\times[c,d]$. For $y_0\in[c,d]$ you wish to see how the difference
$$ F(y)-f(y_0)=\int^b_af(x,y)-f(x,y_0)\,dx$$
behave when $y$ is close to $y_0$. The assumption of continuity of $f$ is key here.

I ignore if you are aware of the notion of [uniform continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity). Here is more or less how the story goes (I am not a great story teller though):

> For a continuous function on say, a box $C=[a,b]\times[c,d]$, uniform continuity >implies that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that for any part >of points $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')\in C$,
> $$ \begin{align}\|(x,y) - (x',y')\|<\delta\quad\text{implies}\quad|f(x,y)-f(x',y')|<\varepsilon\tag{1}\label{one}\end{align}$$
> This is stronger that mere continuity in the sense that the $\delta>0$ depends only  $\varepsilon$ and not on any particular point in $C$.

This can then be used in your favor to attack the problem. For
$$
|F(y)-F(y_0)|\leq\int^b_a|f(x,y)-f(x,y_0)|\,dy
$$
So, given $\varepsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that \eqref{one} holds,  what can you say of $|F(y)-F(y_0)|$?

Comment: so it is $\leq\int_{a}^{b} \epsilon$ and if we choose $\epsilon/(b-a)$ in (1) we can conclude that $F$ is continous right?

Comment: Correct. That's it.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It was a really good story telling btw :)